# If a char is a small integer then why can it contain symbols?

Tags: c

If a `char` is a small integer, why can it contain symbols?

Comment: A char doesn't contain symbols. Rather, there is a standard for "this number encodes this symbol". See ASCII. You see symbols and not numbers because the display-er knows how to convert the numbers into the patterns of pixels we see

Comment: Symbols are actually numbers: see [this ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: Do you mean [How does UTF-8 work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)?

Comment: Software only contains numbers, nothing else. You cannot store letters or pictures in memory, you can only store binary numbers

Comment: @tadman, sorry, but utf-8 is not related to this question.  That's only an encoding, but many different can be used to encode characters into display symbols (see EBCDIC, Windows code pages, ASCII, etc)

Comment: @LuisColorado Sure, but UTF-8 is the most common when talking about `char*` and it's the only one that can do the full suite of symbols. Other character sets, especially 8-bit code pages, have a very limited subset. It's also designed to play well with languages like C where zero-bytes have special meaning.

Comment: I don't understand when you say _have a very limited subset_. Really... utf is expanding, and utf-8 is actually a good idea.... anyway, the character encoding is not related to this question at all.  The OP is requesting an explanation for an encoding at all... you assume that he know exactly what is.... Are you trying to debate? the specifics of utf-8 only overcomplicate things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char` is a single byte integer, which means at least 256 possibilities (assuming the compiler follows the c standard). The lower 128 (number 0-127 inclusive) include almost all "symbols" you see printed. Here's a list: https://www.asciitable.com/

This often does not include more complicated characters, commonly called "multi-byte characters" which consist of more then 8 bits, such as emojis and eastern Asian word-characters. Different systems have different ways of handling these, but very few use the `char` type in C for more then one byte characters.

As a general rule, treat a `char`/byte like it is exactly 8 bits. Though some systems may allow `char` to be bigger, that's not always the case. Use the platform-specific type for multi-byte characters if you want to use them.

Comment: Why usually? Are there any exceptions when char is not a single byte integer?

Comment: @IlyaMashinin When it's passed to a function with variable arguments, such as `printf`. Or when it's converted into an `int` and passed to a `ctype` function.

Comment: @IlyaMashinin In C, a char is defined as a byte, so is always a single byte integer. In some exotic systems, one byte is 16 bits. But almost always, a byte is 8 bits, so a char is 8 bits.

Comment: That doesn't cause `char` to not be a single byte; `sizeof(char)` will always return 1. What happens in that case is that the value of the `char` is temporarily stored in a larger space.

Comment: Note that the standard guarantees that a byte is at least 8 bits, but it could be longer. POSIX guarantees that a byte is exactly 8 bits.

Comment: There could be any number of possibilities from 255 upwards.  256 is just a common setup

Comment: I said "usually" because there's nothing to stop a specific compiler implementation from deciding that it should be a different size, or even allowing it to be redefined (e.g. typedef), as well as to avoid confusing with other types of similar names, such as wchar_t on windows. As a rule, if someone *might* have been chosen to do something slightly differently, there is probably a system out there in which it was.
I admit though that I had not considered the possibility that a "byte" might be a different size.

Comment: @JL2210 Huh? What do `printf` and variable arguments lists have to do with it?  In ANSI C (and all the way back to K&R) `char` is always a single byte integer. If you're talking about promotions that's not an example of a `char` not being a single byte. It's an example of a `char` being promoted to a _different_ type.

Comment: @CareyGregory Calling a function requires some specific handling of arguments at the machine code level, which is way beyond the scope of this question. The point is, when working on a 64-bit target, every argument is generally padded up to 64-bits, unless there are so many arguments that they can't all fit in the registers. See function section of this asm reference: https://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs033/docs/guides/x64_cheatsheet.pdf (section 4.4.1)

Comment: @memtha Yeah, I get all that, but you're right that it's way beyond the scope of this question. My point was that telling the OP chars aren't always chars is really misleading. What happens beneath the covers at the assembly level is irrelevant here.

Comment: @CareyGregory Yes, but all other times `char` looks like `char` (i.e. to `sizeof` and initializers). I was just dumbing it down for the OP.

Comment: ... No multi-byte characters will ever be able to fit in a `char`. A `char` is only one byte.

Comment: Also, I'd generally use `CHAR_BIT` bits in a `char` instead of only 8.